# java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException on repeating decimal to fraction calculator

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm new to java and I'm trying to code a method that takes a repeating decimal and turns it into a fraction. It takes input like (double decimal without repeating, int number of trailing digits to repeat) i.e. (0.3,1) would be 0.3333.... and (1.583,2) would be 1.5838383....
I am getting this error and I can't seem to find out what the problem is. The current input is (10.3,1)

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
at Fraction.<init>(Fraction.java:44)
at Main.main(Main.java:12)
exited with non-zero status
```

Heres my code:

```
public Fraction(double t, int repeating)
{
    double decRight = t, decLeft = t;
    String rStr = "0000000000000000000" + String.valueOf(decRight);
    String lStr = "0000000000000000000" + String.valueOf(decLeft);
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0, rDecIndex = rStr.indexOf("."), lDecIndex = lStr.indexOf(".");
    while(!lStr.substring(lDecIndex - repeating,lDecIndex).replace("\\.","").equals(lStr)) //this is line 44, the problem area
    {
        decLeft *= 10;
        count1++;
        lStr = "0000000000000000000" + String.valueOf(decLeft);
        lDecIndex = lStr.indexOf(".");
    }
    while(!rStr.substring(rDecIndex,repeating).replace("\\.","").equals(rStr))
    {
        decRight*= 10;
        count2++;
        rStr = "0000000000000000000" + String.valueOf(decRight);
        rDecIndex = rStr.indexOf(".");
    }
    top = (int)(decLeft - decRight);
    bot = (int)(Math.pow(10,count1) - Math.pow(10,count2));
    reduce();
}
```

The error is in the substring.

Comment: that is far too much logic inside the condition of a while loop. And makes it impossible to debug.

Comment: `replaceAll(".","")` uses regex and in regex `.` represents *any* character (except line separators).

Comment: @Pshemo i escaped the . with \\. but the error persists

Comment: How your code is running without return type in function **Fraction**

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(java.lang.String) - _Returns:
    the index of the first occurrence of the specified substring, **or -1 if there is no such occurrence**._ <- IndexOf will return -1 if there is no dot in the String you supply. You probably need to check first if there is any dot at all before you try to do operations on it or handle those cases differently.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS I dont see how there can't be a dot. The code takes the double input, converts it into a string, then takes the index of the dot, then substrings from that index. I don't understand.

Comment: Can you explain what is supposed to end up in lStr and rString?  IE Given 0.3, 1 as input what should top and bot be at the end?  Same for 1.580,2 as input.

Comment: @Loren https://www.basic-mathematics.com/converting-repeating-decimals-to-fractions.html lStr is supposed to hold the decimal for the part of the function that puts the repeating digits on the left of the decimal. The while loop is supposed to check left of the decimal on lStr and see if it equals what the repeating digits are. IE in (0.3,1)  lStr holds 0.3, and the while loop checks if the one digit to the left of the decimal equal the repeating, which in this case is 3. For (1.580,2) the while loop checks if the two digits left of the decimal equal 80.

Comment: @ArthurPetroff: Another possibilty on how you might get -1 in the substring method is if `lDecIndex - repeating` would be -1. What values are you passing into the function?

Comment: My function below actually works now.  I've omitted computing the denominator as that wasn't part of the question, but I've provided example outputs with one computed.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS lDecIndex is the index of the . on lStr, and repeating is how many digit places from the right are repeating (ie repeating on 0.333333.. would be 1 and on 0.385858585... would be 2).

Comment: `0.385858585... would be 2` <- The index of the dot here is at 1, so `lDecIndex - repeating` would be `1-2` = `-1` and you get your error.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you wanted `lDecIndex, lDecIndex+repeating` not `lDecIndex-repeating, lDecIndex`.  Alternatively, my example gives you the values/Strings you wanted for before and repeating, you just need to work them into the rest of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, you want an integer with the repeating decimal in it and an integer with what is before the repeating part.

I think you've gone about this the hard way rather than just using substring to get the parts of the string that you want.

```
/**
 * Code By Loren CC-BY
 */
public class test
{
    public static void fraction(String t, int repeating)
    {
        int bot = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < repeating; i++) {
            bot *= 10;
            bot += 9;
        }
        String dString = t;
        // Get the repeating part of the string as an int
        int repeat = Integer.valueOf(dString.substring(dString.length()-repeating));
        // Get the string from in front of the repeating number
        String front = dString.substring(0, dString.length()-repeating);
        // Convert it to a double
        double before = Double.valueOf(front);
        // Debugging information
        System.out.println("Before: "+ front+" " +before+" "+dString.substring(dString.length()-repeating));

        // Turn the before string into an int and compute the denominator such that 1.5 could become 15/10
        int count = 0;
        while (Math.abs(Math.round(before) - before) > 0.000001) {
            before *= 10;
            count++;
        }
        // Print debugging information
        System.out.println(count);
        // Compute the top of the combined fraction
        int top = ((int)before)*bot+repeat;

        bot = (int)Math.pow(10,count) * bot;
        System.out.println(top+" "+bot);
        // TODO: Reduce fraction
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        fraction("0.3",1);
        fraction("1.580",2);
        fraction("0.34",1);
        fraction("0.34",2);
    }
}
```

**Note: You can't pass in the double 1.580 because that as a string is 1.58 not 1.580 as the 0 is omitted which messes up the function.**

Comment: I don't believe this works. For the input (0.42,2) it says the numerator is 42. I checked on a calculator and 0.424242... is 14/33. I don't understand what your while loop is doing.

Comment: You still have to reduce (as in your previous function). 42/99 (which should be the bottom) reduces by dividing top and bottom by 3 to 14/33.  Just as 3/9 reduces to 1/3 and 1565/990 to 313/198.

Comment: Sorry, it actually doesn't quite work as intended. I tried (0.34,1) which should mean 0.343434... but it gave me 4/9 which is 0.4444....

Comment: No, (0.34,1) would be 0.344444.  (0.34,2) would be 0.343434.  In my complete program 0.34,1 results in Before: 0.3 0.3 4 and 31/90, 0.34, 2 is Before: 0. 0.0 34 and 34/99.

Comment: I couldn't get yours to work, so I tried again to fix mine. I told it to always put a bunch of dummy zeroes in the beginning of lStr and rStr so substring wouldn't go in the negatives but it's still happening.

Comment: I recommend adding some print statements so you can see what is happening and debug it. (IE Since when it should be quitting but isn't.)

Comment: FYI: I've added my full function which works (without reducing) on all the items you've given so far.

Answer (score 0):

For Converting repeating decimals to fractions could you try the following:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ConvertRepeatingNumbersToFraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        convertToFraction("0.3",1);
        convertToFraction("1.580",2);
        convertToFraction("0.16",1);
        convertToFraction("0.34",2);
        convertToFraction("0.42",2);
        convertToFraction("0.34",1);
    }



    private static void convertToFraction(String x, int numOfRepeatingDigits) {

        int denominator = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfRepeatingDigits; i++) {
            denominator = denominator * 10 + 9;
        }

        int repeatingNumber = Integer.valueOf(x.substring(x.length() - numOfRepeatingDigits));
        double numerator = Double.valueOf(x.substring(0, x.length() - numOfRepeatingDigits));

        int count = 0;
        if (numerator % 1 != 0) {
            numerator = numerator * 10;
            count++;
        }

        numerator = numerator * denominator + repeatingNumber;
        denominator = (int) Math.pow(10, count) * denominator;

        int[] fraction = reduce((int)numerator, denominator);
        System.out.println(fraction[0] + "/" + fraction[1]);
    }

    private static int[] reduce(int num, int den) {
        // common divisor
        int commonDivisor = BigInteger.valueOf(num).gcd(BigInteger.valueOf(den)).intValue();
        return new int[]{ num / commonDivisor, den / commonDivisor };
    }
}
```

I have checked the test numbers on http://onlinecalculators.brainmeasures.com/Numbers/RecurringDecimalNumbertoFraction.aspx and the result are the same.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: This looks very like you copied most of my answer and added a little of your own. If so, it would be appropriate to cite my answer as the basis for yours. Also, I don't beige that %1 will deal with possible round off error when multiplying by 10 which is why I have greater than 0.0001